# how would i make myself a domain without using a host

Tags: php, html

I'm wondering how would i make a domain for my website without using a host like Wix.
I've already tried to use  `<meta property="og:url" content="https://limonthunderservice.com" />`, and I've looked everywhere on the internet, but I just cant find what I'm looking for.
Also I'm gonna try using a Raspberry pi for my web host.

Comment: Are you trying to host a website on your own computer, on a different host, or something else. Either I'm missing something significant or you don't understand the systems behind [how websites work](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-host-a-website/). Please elaborate on what you are trying to do, since your current question doesn't really explain it.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are looking for. There are domain name servers like [sslip](https://sslip.io/) that answer to subdomains containing IP addresses. These are free.

Comment: All websites have to be hosted somewhere. The way websites work is that when someone loads a website, a request is sent over the internet to a server (which is a kind of computer), which then sends a response containing the contents of the website. So all websites need to be hosted on a server. The easiest way to do this is to use a hosting company which lets you use one of their servers. The only way to avoid that is to use your own computer as a server, but setting that up would be very complicated and would require your computer to be running all the time, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, it's not that difficult to set up a personal computer to host a site, since there's plenty of software bundles (XAMPP for instance) that will set up the majority of it for you. The hard part is securing it to prevent hacking. Even pointing the DNS to the computer is fairly easy. But keeping it set when you don't have a static public IP address takes a lot of work. I've self-hosted before, and the IP address was probably the most annoying part, although I didn't do any real security, so I'm lucky I didn't get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

The way domains work is that when you type a name it gets send to what's called a DNS (Domain Name System), that DNS then finds the IP associated with that name and connects you to it.

To acquire a domain you have to register it with a service such as [Google domains](https://domains.google/), then associate that domain with the IP of your server.